# detect which part of the email has body in HTML format

Tags: php, email, imap

I am trying to read emails of two different kinds.

One kind of email has html body under part number 2, which I am able to read by doing,

```
imap_fetchbody($imap_connection, $imap_msgno, '2');
```

The other kind has the html body under part 1.2, for which I use the following to get the body,

```
imap_fetchbody($imap_connection, $imap_msgno, '1.2');
```

Now my question is how do I know which part has the email's html body ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using a library, which handles this.

I was working with mails some time and it is not that easy. There may be multiple parts, where the HTML body is located (for example when you respond to someone's mail, there is one part (the original message) and another part (your response) under two different ids. The best way to get email body is to parse object returned by `imap_fetchstructure($imap_connection, $imap_msgno);`. But it's pain in ass, i know what i'm talking about.

So back to my suggestion, one of the libraries is mine and you can use it freely: https://github.com/greeny/MailLibrary

Comment: I would love to use that library of yours, looks fantastic, but unfortunately I don't have much time to try out a new lib, I am settling for a hack I invented [check out my answer for more] Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am reading both and trying to find out which one has the html,

Here is my hack which works for me.

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($imap_connection, $imap_msgno, '2'); 
//read the body assuming its type 2

//apply respective decoding function here. eg, imap_base64 OR imap_8bit 
//OR imap_qprint based on the email's encoding info.

if($message == strip_tags($message)) { //checking if the $message has html tags.
    //if no html, read the other part.
    $message = imap_fetchbody($imap_connection, $imap_msgno, '1.2');
    // ..... 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this with more complex messages? (For example a response to another mail, which had attachments?)

Comment: no, I am only parsing specific type of forwarded emails. So all other types of mails(having attachments, responses) will be ignored.